# How to open pdf and text files in browser using href link in jsp

Tags: java, jsp, href

I am trying to list the files in a folder and when click on the file names it need to open it the browser.
The code is given below

```
<c:forEach  var="files" items="${allfiles}">
<p>
<a target="_blank" href="D:/dy/MIV Files/"+${files}>${files}</a>
</p>
</c:forEach>
```

is there any way to do this?

Comment: what happen when you try above code ? Also why `+` before `${files}` ?

Comment: @Swati now on click nothing happens. The + is used to concatenate strings.

Comment: href which you have given is correct ? did you check that in browsers element tab  ?

Comment: @Swati in elements it shows like this ```<a target="_blank" href="D:/dy/MIV Files/" +24311vg10281-01_1-0-0--001.pdf="">24311VG10281-01_1-0-0--001.pdf</a>```

Comment: ofcourse that not right href ? Your code should be somewhat like this - > `href="D:/dy/MIV Files/${files}"` change it and see what element tab show .

Comment: @Swati I changed the code, removed the + now the code is like this ```<a target="_blank" href="D:/dy/MIV Files/${files}">${files}</a>``` . the link is correct now but when clicking on it shows an error ```Not allowed to load local resource: file:///D:/dy/MIV%20Files/24311VG10281-01_1-0-0--001.pdf```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219904/discussion-between-swati-and-alvin-john-niravukalayil).